# Add a new attribute(pwdLastAuthTime) to existing users in LDAP

Tags: attributes, ldap, addition

LDAP gurus,

I have imported users from LDIF file which had the pwdLastAuthTime as an attribute and I enabled the attribute with the following

```
./dsconf set-server-prop -p <port> pwd-keep-last-auth-time-enabled:on
```

But I do not see the values populated nor the attribute. So I tried to do ldapmodify as below

```
ldapmodify -c -x -h <host> -p <port> -D "" -w <> -f fileMod.ldif
```

the file is

```
dn: uid=abcd,ou=aa,dc=aa,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: pwdLastAuthTime
pwdLastAuthTime: 20140214195614Z
```

But I get the following error

```
ldap_modify: Constraint violation (19)
        additional info: Constraint violation in modifications
```

How do I add this attribute to all the users? I also need to be able to create the modify files from the LDIF files. Any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the pwdLastAuthTime is an operational attribute, maintained by the Directory Server, and read-only. It is added to entries, when the user authenticates (if the password policy is properly configured, as you've done with the dsconf command). But you cannot directly add, delete or modify the attribute over LDAP. Only the import process allows to set initial values to entries.
Note that since the attribute is used to identify when a user has last authenticated against the directory, it doesn't make sense to populate initial values. I would treat the absence of the attribute as the user hasn't authenticated since this property has been setup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But we are trying to migrate the users to another LDAP and we cannot replicate them. All we have is the LDIF file and we need them imported. I tried with the dscc ui and I was able to see the pwdLastAuthTime, but the changelog was not populated. I kind of need both for my scenario. Thanks.